# rbenv: passenger-status: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am using Rails 5.2 with Ruby 2.5.8. passenger-status command was working before but it stopped working after moving from Ruby 2.3.5 to 2.5.8. May I know how to get the passenger-status command back? it wasn't in Gemfile earlier so I don't think I need to put it there.

Here are my settings

```
$ passenger-status
rbenv: passenger-status: command not found

The `passenger-status' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.2
  2.3.5

$ which passenger
/home/cyborg/.rbenv/shims/passenger

$ passenger --version
rbenv: passenger: command not found

The `passenger' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.2
  2.3.5
```

Comment: What is the version of passenger in your system? Also just to clarify, do you need to use `passenger` with ruby version 2.5.8 or 2.3.5?

Comment: @Yedhin passenger --versoin is giving passenger: command not found.

Comment: You can also check the 'passenger' in your Gemfile.lock file. However, if you bumped the ruby version, you should make sure you $`bundle update` your app Gemfile before, to match the new ruby version. Then, you can try again using $`sudo passenger-status` or $`rvmsudo bundle exec passenger-status`. reference: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/overall_status_report.html

Answer (score 0):

Passenger is a gem, and it doesn't look like you have it installed for your new version of Ruby. While using Ruby 2.5.8, I think you need to run `gem install passenger`. That will install the libraries and the executables that you're missing for the new Ruby version, but if you're using Passenger as a module for Apache or another web server, then you'll probably also need to recompile/reinstall that module.